# My camera is "double lerping" when I enter a new section of my map in LibGDX

Tags: java, camera, libgdx

In my game, I'm dividing my map into "sections", sort of like the way Celeste does it. However, when I move into a new section of my map, the camera is doing a weird "double-lerp"-looking thing. How can I fix this so that the camera just moves smoothly into the next sect of my map?

Sorry for the external link but its hard to explain so here's a video: https://youtu.be/rlNzvIwYfj4

Here's my code for moving the camera:

```
    private void moveCamera(boolean changingSect) {
        
        float playerCenterX = player.getRect().x + 0.5f * player.getRect().width;
        float playerCenterY = player.getRect().y + 0.5f * player.getRect().height;
        
        if(map.cameraAttachPlayer || map.mapSections.size == 0) { // just follow the player
            camera.position.lerp(new Vector3(playerCenterX, playerCenterY, 0), 0.1f);
            return;
        }
        
        Rectangle mapSect = player.sectIn;
        
        Vector2 sectCenter = new Vector2();
        mapSect.getCenter(sectCenter);
        
        //if sect is completely on screen, just look at the middle of the sect
        if(sectFitsScreen(mapSect)) {
            camera.position.lerp(new Vector3(sectCenter.x, sectCenter.y, 0), 0.1f);
            return;
        }
        
        else if(sectFitsVertically(mapSect, true)) {
            //if left is visible, stop moving left and vice versa
            //right visible
            if(camera.position.x + camera.viewportWidth/2 > mapSect.x+mapSect.width) {
                if(playerInHThird(false)) { // if in bottom third
                    camera.position.lerp(new Vector3(playerCenterX, sectCenter.y, 0), 0.1f);
                } else {
                    camera.position.lerp(new Vector3(mapSect.x+mapSect.width-camera.viewportWidth/2, sectCenter.y, 0), 0.1f);
                }
                return;
            }
            
            //left visible
            else if(camera.position.x - camera.viewportWidth/2 < mapSect.x) {
                if(playerInHThird(true)) { // if in top third
                    camera.position.lerp(new Vector3(playerCenterX, sectCenter.y, 0), 0.1f);
                } else {
                    camera.position.lerp(new Vector3(mapSect.x+camera.viewportWidth/2, sectCenter.y, 0), 0.1f);
                }
                return;
            }

            //neither visible
            else {
                camera.position.lerp(new Vector3(playerCenterX, sectCenter.y, 0), 0.1f);
                return;
            }
        } else if(sectFitsHorizontally(mapSect, true)) {
            //if ceiling is visible, stop moving up and vice versa
            //ceiling visible
            if(camera.position.y + camera.viewportHeight/2 > mapSect.y+mapSect.height) {
                if(playerInVThird(false)) { // if in bottom third
                    camera.position.lerp(new Vector3(sectCenter.x, playerCenterY, 0), 0.1f);
                } else {
                    camera.position.lerp(new Vector3(sectCenter.x, mapSect.y+mapSect.height-camera.viewportHeight/2, 0), 0.1f);
                }
                return;
            }
            
            //floor visible
            else if(camera.position.y - camera.viewportHeight/2 < mapSect.y) {
                if(playerInVThird(true)) { // if in top third
                    camera.position.lerp(new Vector3(sectCenter.x, playerCenterY, 0), 0.1f);
                } else {
                    camera.position.lerp(new Vector3(sectCenter.x, mapSect.y+camera.viewportHeight/2, 0), 0.1f);
                }
                return;
            }
            
            //neither visible
            else {
                camera.position.lerp(new Vector3(sectCenter.x, playerCenterY, 0), 0.1f);
                return;
            }
            
        } else { //neither at all
            
            boolean ceilingVisible = camera.position.y + camera.viewportHeight/2 > mapSect.y+mapSect.height;
            boolean floorVisible = camera.position.y - camera.viewportHeight/2 < mapSect.y;
            boolean leftVisible = camera.position.x - camera.viewportWidth/2 < mapSect.x;
            boolean rightVisible = camera.position.x + camera.viewportWidth/2 > mapSect.x+mapSect.width;
            
            float lerpX = playerCenterX;
            float lerpY = playerCenterY;
            
            //none visible
            if(!ceilingVisible && !floorVisible && !leftVisible && !rightVisible) {
                camera.position.lerp(new Vector3(lerpX, lerpY, 0), 0.1f);
                return;
            }
            
            if(ceilingVisible) {
                if(!playerInVThird(false)) { // if in bottom third
                    lerpY = mapSect.y+mapSect.height-camera.viewportHeight/2;
                }
            } else if(floorVisible) {
                if(!playerInVThird(true)) { // if in top third
                    lerpY = mapSect.y+camera.viewportHeight/2;
                }
            }
            
            if(rightVisible) {
                if(!playerInHThird(false)) { // if in left third
                    lerpX = mapSect.x+mapSect.width-camera.viewportWidth/2;
                }
            } else if(leftVisible) {
                if(!playerInHThird(true)) { // if in right third
                    lerpX = mapSect.x+camera.viewportWidth/2;
                }
            }
            
            camera.position.lerp(new Vector3(lerpX, lerpY, 0), 0.1f);
        }
```